# Git History object hash recalculation

Tags: git, hashing

I'm trying to write a git history rewriter that I have completed Pack file Reader and Writer(also IDX file too) already.
now I change a commit content and recalculate the hash of the new object and I should replace the old hash with a new hash in other objects

With the help of [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), I know how to recalculate hash of commit, blob, tree, and tag object type but I want to recalculate ref_delta or ofs_delta hash

how ref_delta or ofs_delta hashes can be calculated?

I didn't find any documentation about ref_delta or ofs_delta hash calculation

Comment: Sounds like you want to amend an old commit and rebase its descendants: `git checkout <theCommit>; git add <changes>; git commit --amend --no-edit; git checkout -; git rebase -p -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REF_DELTA` and `OFS_DELTA` types aren't real types of objects.

When Git stores an object in a pack file, it may create a delta against another object to avoid needing to store the entirety of the object when those objects are very similar.  These two types of entries in a pack file are a way of recording that there's a delta against another object.  They aren't independent objects themselves, and you'll need to resolve the delta against the base to get the full object, which you can then rewrite and hash.

You may be interested in reading `Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt` in the Git repository, which defines these.

Comment: so you mean I should apply the delta to base object then recalculate base object hash?
what is the id of deltas in the pack file, the id of commit object are sha1 of the content, how about deltas

Comment: You should apply the delta to the base object to get the second object and then hash that.  There is no object ID of the delta itself; the object ID is of the object which is deltified and it is computed the same as a regular undeltaed object once the delta is resolved and the original object recovered.